# Remove rows from a dataframe with minimum value out of all pair of adjacent rows whose relative difference is less than threshold

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe df with columns "x_center", "width", "confidence" etc. all having float values. I have calculated another column called "relative_xc_diff" which is the relative difference in "x_center" values with respect to "width" values.

```
x_centers = df["x_center"].values
relative_xc_diff = (abs(x_centers[1:] - x_centers[:-1]) / df["width"].values[:-1]) * 100
df["relative_xc_diff"] = 0
df["relative_x_diff"].values[1:] = relative_xc_diff
```

Now I need to check if for any pair of rows, "relative_xc_diff" < 50, if that's the case, I need to keep only that row whose "confidence" is larger and drop the one with lower confidence.

So if my initial dataframe is like this:

```
   x_center  y_center    width   height  confidence  relative_xc_diff 
0  0.28197   0.30739  0.11030  0.28363     0.83297           0.000000  
1  0.41412   0.32434  0.11954  0.27971     0.84027         119.809610  
2  0.59346   0.34406  0.10318  0.28965     0.83406         150.025096  
3  0.71342   0.36437  0.10287  0.28662     0.78227         116.262842  
4  0.13095   0.70592  0.12195  0.27470     0.86141         566.219500  
5  0.18598   0.71642  0.10878  0.27158     0.77353          45.125051   
6  0.45247   0.75308  0.10018  0.28254     0.76669         244.980695  
7  0.57028   0.77230  0.09996  0.28853     0.81539         117.598323  
8  0.60460   0.78803  0.10151  0.28281     0.82202          34.333733   
9  0.80243   0.80597  0.10614  0.29262     0.77144         194.887203  
10  0.96391   0.77255  0.07218  0.44827     0.30487        152.138685
```

I need to drop the rows with index 5 and 7 (note that the first value of "relative_xc_diff" is meaningless so I need to ignore it)

Answer (score 0):

Use [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with set first value to `True` and chain another mask for test difference of `confidence`. If `False` test previous values by shift and chain conditions with `&` for bitwise `AND` and `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
m1 = (df['x_center'].diff().abs().div(df["width"].shift())
                                .mul(100).fillna(0).le(50))

m1.iat[0] = False

m2 = df["confidence"].diff().le(0)

m = (m1 & m2) | (m1.shift(-1, fill_value=False) & m2)

out = df[~m]
print (out)
    x_center  y_center    width   height  confidence
0    0.28197   0.30739  0.11030  0.28363     0.83297
1    0.41412   0.32434  0.11954  0.27971     0.84027
2    0.59346   0.34406  0.10318  0.28965     0.83406
3    0.71342   0.36437  0.10287  0.28662     0.78227
4    0.13095   0.70592  0.12195  0.27470     0.83141
6    0.45247   0.75308  0.10018  0.28254     0.76669
7    0.57028   0.77230  0.09996  0.28853     0.81539
8    0.68460   0.78803  0.10151  0.28281     0.82202
9    0.80243   0.80597  0.10614  0.29262     0.77144
10   0.96391   0.77255  0.07218  0.44827     0.30487
```

How it working:

```
print (df.assign(m1=m1, m2=m2, m=m))
    x_center  y_center    width   height  confidence     m1     m2      m
0    0.28197   0.30739  0.11030  0.28363     0.83297  False  False  False
1    0.41412   0.32434  0.11954  0.27971     0.84027  False  False  False
2    0.59346   0.34406  0.10318  0.28965     0.83406  False   True  False
3    0.71342   0.36437  0.10287  0.28662     0.78227  False   True  False
4    0.13095   0.70592  0.12195  0.27470     0.83141  False  False  False
5    0.18598   0.71642  0.10878  0.27158     0.77353   True   True   True
6    0.45247   0.75308  0.10018  0.28254     0.76669  False   True  False
7    0.57028   0.77230  0.09996  0.28853     0.81539  False  False  False
8    0.68460   0.78803  0.10151  0.28281     0.82202  False  False  False
9    0.80243   0.80597  0.10614  0.29262     0.77144  False   True  False
10   0.96391   0.77255  0.07218  0.44827     0.30487  False   True  False
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need to find the row with the maximum confidence value out of the pair of rows with their "relative_xc_diff" < 50; Suppose, in this case if the "confidence" value of 4th row is less than that of 5th, then I need to remove the 4th and keep the 5th. Your answer is not taking that into account.

Comment: It is not working for all cases. Let's say the "x_center" value of 8th row is changed from 0.68460 to 0.60460; in that case the "relative_xc_diff" value between 8th and 7th row will be 34.333733, Here I need to remove the 7th row (with lower confidence) but your answer doesn't remove any of the two rows. 

`8  0.60460   0.78803  0.10151  0.28281   0.82202    True  False  False`

Comment: @rajput_18 - Can you modify sample data with this scenario?

Comment: I have updated the sample data

Comment: I have update the sample data @jezrael